# Datefield is not populating in Razor Pages

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, razor-pages, asp.net-core-3.1

My Razor Pages edit screen is not populating datefield, all the other fields are populating correctly
[image]

Checked database table,the format is '2020-12-29 00:00:00.000'
in my model class the dateformat im passing is

```
        //--Start Date ---//
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please select Start Date")]
        [Display(Name = "Start Date*")]
        [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:dd/MM/yyyy}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
        [DataType(DataType.Date)]
        public DateTime Startdate { get; set; }
```

Comment: Can you share the view code >

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use `asp-for` tag helper for the DateTime field, the generated html element will be like this: `<input type= "date" />` , by default the date format is "mm/dd/yyyy" and seems not allow other dateformat. However you could try to change it to `text` type.

```
<input asp-for="Startdate" type="text" class="datepicker" />
```

then use [bootstrap datepicker](https://bootstrap-datepicker.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) to allow it select date.

```
<script src="~/lib/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/lib/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.9.0/js/bootstrap-datepicker.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.9.0/css/bootstrap-datepicker.min.css" />

<script>
    $('.datepicker').datepicker({
        format: 'dd/mm/yyyy'
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Hi @mj1313 , Thanks for the explanation. I have changed the type to text and copied the jquery snippets in '_ValidationScriptsPartial.cshtml' file. But whats happening now is the date is displaying as expected but the calendar icon is not showing and im not able to select a date.

Comment: Hi @mj1313, i managed to fix the issue. changed the input class to datepicker.Now its working fine.Thanks for the help.

Comment: @Teena I forgot to add the class sorry:)

Comment: @ mj1313 no worries :)